# How can I transpose a field-value table into a normal in ABAP?

Tags: csv, file, dynamic, abap

I should create a file with a horizontal table.

I have this table:

| FIELDNAME | FIELDVALUE |
| --- | --- |
| ZFIELD1 | A |
| ZFIELD2 | B |
| ZFIELD3 | C |
| ZFIELD4 | D |

[image: image of table]

File will be:

| ZFIELD1 | ZFIELD2 | ZFIELD2 | ZFIELD2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D |

How can I do this code?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, all you need to do is loop through the table and write the values of column FIELDNAME to a file and then loop through the table again and write the values of column FIELDVALUE to the same file. To provide a code example I would need some more information: should the file be stored on the server or downloaded to the frontend? What is the exact file format (plain text, CSV, tab delimited,...)

Comment: Download csv file to local desktop

Comment: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65356112/how-to-transpose-a-field-value-table-into-a-normal-in-abap/65464531#65464531) (now deleted) is the subject of the canonical meta question *[When should answers consisting entirely of cited, copied content be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404102/)*.

Answer (score 2):

A short example how to create a CSV file in your scenario:

```
CONSTANTS:
  lc_filename TYPE string VALUE `C:\Myfile.csv`.

DATA:
  l_fieldnames  TYPE string,
  l_fieldvalues TYPE string,
  l_csv_file    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string.

FIELD-SYMBOLS:
  <l_workarea> LIKE LINE OF gt_prepare_file.

* Create CSV lines
LOOP AT gt_prepare_file ASSIGNING <l_workarea>.
  PERFORM csv_encode USING <l_workarea>-fieldname CHANGING l_fieldnames.
  PERFORM csv_encode USING <l_workarea>-fieldvalue CHANGING l_fieldvalues.
ENDLOOP.

* Create CSV file
INSERT l_fieldnames INTO TABLE l_csv_file.
INSERT l_fieldvalues INTO TABLE l_csv_file.

* Download CSV file
CALL METHOD cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download
  EXPORTING
    filename = lc_filename
  CHANGING
    data_tab = l_csv_file.


* Add a value to a line of the CSV file
FORM csv_encode USING value TYPE string CHANGING target TYPE string.
  CONSTANTS:
    lc_separator         TYPE string VALUE `,`,
    lc_delimiter         TYPE string VALUE `"`,
    lc_escaped_delimiter TYPE string VALUE `""`.

  DATA:
    l_encoded_value TYPE string.

* Use delimiter if value contains separator
  l_encoded_value = value.

  IF value CS lc_separator.
    REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF lc_delimiter IN l_encoded_value WITH lc_escaped_delimiter.
    CONCATENATE lc_delimiter l_encoded_value lc_delimiter INTO l_encoded_value.
  ENDIF.

* Add value to line
  IF target IS INITIAL.
    target = l_encoded_value.
  ELSE.
    CONCATENATE target lc_separator l_encoded_value INTO target.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.
```

Please adjust the constants and add some error handling to the code. If you want to use the CSV file in Microsoft Excel, be aware that the separator character is a country specific setting.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way,

- Create a flat table `standard table of string`
- Retrieve the fields of your table from the `DD03L` table
- Concatenate the field names in a string, and add it to your flat table
- Loop through the data of the table and for each field name (from DD03L struct) assigns the value (`assign component of structure`), concatenate the values, and once the loop on the field names is finished, add it to your table.

You can easily transform your flat table into a horizontal table.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dynamic table in ABAP and fill the field catalog manually. Then you can show this table in ALV. Check the blog post *[Dynamic internal table iilustrated with an example of creating the transpose of internal table](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/11/dynamic-internal-table-iilustrated-with-an-example-of-creating-the-transpose-of-internal-table/)*.

Comment: Please ["provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) as per Stack Overflow rules. If the blog post you mention is deleted, your answer will be meaningless.